# clone object with unique name in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, list

I'm new to Angular and looking for a way to make a clone button inside a list.

When I click this button, it will clone the object and add a number to the object name:

"new test" - will be changed to "new test (2)" and so on...

It requires to check the last 3 letters every time and check all the objects every time.

Is there any library doing this?

Comment: can you provide sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any lib for this. Basically, it you need one loop that looks for duplicates. See an example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = ['Sample item'];
  $scope.suggestedNewName = 'Sample item';
  var isNameOccupied = function(name) {
    return $scope.items.indexOf(name) >= 0;
  };
  $scope.addNewItem = function(){
    var suggestedName = $scope.suggestedNewName;
    var newName = suggestedName;
    for (var i = 2; isNameOccupied(newName); i++) {
      newName = suggestedName + " (" + i + ")";  
    }
    $scope.items.push(newName);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="addNewItem()">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <label>Suggested name for new item:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="suggestedNewName">
    <button type="submit">Add new item!</button>
  </form>
</div>
```